# what causes the difference in interpretation of = and == in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I recently updated to Ubuntu 13.04 and one of my shell scripts broke with this:

```
#!/bin/sh    
...
if [ "$SHOW_USAGE" == "true" ]; then

./install.sh: 248: [: false: unexpected operator
```

Now, I understand that I can fix this by replacing the double-equal ('==') with a single equal ('='), but what caused this difference in Ubuntu behavior between 13.04 and previous Ubuntu releases? And is there a way to restore the more flexible interpretation that the previous releases had?

Comment: depends on what shell you're using. some shells now have `[` integrated as a built-in command, so if your previous install was actually using `/usr/bin/test` (which is symlinked to `[`), you'll get different behavior.

Comment: "=" may be used instead of "==" for strict POSIX compliance.` From TLDP

Comment: I edited the question to show that I'm using #!/bin/sh (and I need to keep it that way for maximum compatibility).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/bin/sh` (not `/bin.sh` as written in your post) used to be linked to `/bin/bash`, but is now linked to `/bin/dash` on Ubuntu. bash tolerates some bashisms even when called as sh.

Comment: That looks like the right answer...although on closer inspection, I see that '/bin/sh' has been linked to '/bin/dash' on Ubuntu since at least 10.10. I actually noticed the behavior change between CentOS 6.4 and Ubuntu, and sure enough CentOS has sh linked to bash.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind requiring `bash` to run your script, you can use bash's `[[` instead of trying to use `[`.  There is some different behaviour, but `[[` does support `==` operator, while `[` never has (except maybe as an extension on particular systems).

Edit:  Since you're using `sh`, the `==` was *never* correct; you were just getting lucky with some particular characteristic of your system setup.

Comment: I just edited the question to show that I'm using #!/bin/sh (for maximum compatibility). I can't require bash.